# Embed yeoman created angularjs application in play framework

Tags: angularjs, playframework, gruntjs, yeoman, playframework-2.3

My target software architecture:

- **Backend-application** (RESTful http API, responding JSON)

  - Play Framework (v2.3.8)
- **Frontend-application** (requests the backend-application and renders the result)

  - AngularJS App
  - Yeoman scaffolded (angular-generator)

**My question:**

> I want to host the angularjs inside the play application. How can I
>   achieve that?

*(I don't want to create a second app and host it with grunt serve since this causes problems because of the 'same origin policy')*

Comment: Just put your front-end assets in your app's public folder.

Comment: I want to profit from all the scaffolding (yeoman) stuff and packaging (grunt) mechanisms. Normally the routes to the assets are not correct when serving in play..

Comment: You really should state all of this clearly in your question. We can't read minds.

Comment: I'll update the question when I'm at the pc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Play Yeoman](https://github.com/tuplejump/play-yeoman). [Here](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed) is a small example application which shows a simple implementation.